# AngularJS losing reference to service variable on re-assignment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I didn't know a better way to phrase that question. I've written a basic service to be used by two controllers.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aditya/2Nd8u/2/

Clicking 'notify' works as expected; it adds a notification to the array. But 'reset' breaks it. Clicking either button after 'reset' doesn't do anything. Does anyone know what's going on here?

PS. I think it has something to do with Angular losing the reference since `notifs` is being re-assigned (technically), so I wrote getters and setters, but even emptying the array involves `pop()`ing till it's empty, which doesn't seem very efficient.

Plunkr if JsFiddle is down: http://plnkr.co/edit/mzfLLjFXCwsxM5KDebhc

Comment: Is JSFiddle down? Taking forever to load over here?

Comment: It's being slow, but it's definitely up here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your service to this:

```
.factory("notificationService", function(){
    var notifications = [];
    return {
        notifs: notifications,
        clear: function(){
            angular.copy([], notifications);
        },
        get: function(){ 
            return notifs; 
        }
    }
})
```

and  your controller :

```
$scope.reset = function(){
        console.log("reset");
        notificationService.clear();
        console.log(notificationService);
    }
```

and it works for me.

Naturally it should be a little bit tidier, in that instead of notifs you should have a get, and add and a remove method, but i just wanted to show you where the code changed.
The `angular.copy` is the method that makes sure the changes are made within angular's lifecycle.

As you can't bind variable but only methods, you could do this:

`$scope.getNotifications = notificationService.get;`

That should work.

Comment: My question was why my code wasn't working. Is this the accepted practice when dealing with objects and Angular? To copy instead of re-assign?

Answer (score 4):

I've forked your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K4UrhQPgyvlF6GRAaDLr?p=preview) and propose a solution:

In reset function, try to remove the objects of the array instead of declaring as new empty array:

```
notificationService.notifs.splice(0, notificationService.notifs.length);
```

Or, like suggested by @Wizcover:

```
notificationService.notifs.length = 0
```

This will notify angular that are modifications in the original array.

Comment: In the same spirit you can do `notificationService.notifs.length = 0` which is more efficient.