# Reload ng-repeat angular / ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I already read some discussions about this problem but no one works for me.

I have a controller

```
.controller('TestFriendCtrl', ['$scope', 'APIUser', function($scope, APIUser) {

        $scope.data.friends = [{username: 'test'}];

        $scope.change = function(friend) {
            APIUser.find(friend, function(success, data){
                if (success) {
                    $scope.data.friends = data;
                    console.log($scope.data.friends);
                }
            })
        }
    }]);
```

I also tried

```
.controller('TestFriendCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'APIUser', function($scope, $timeout, APIUser) {

    $scope.friends = [{username: 'coucou'}];

    $scope.change = function(friend) {
        APIUser.find(friend, function(success, data){
            if (success) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.friends = data;
                    console.log($scope.friends);
                } );
            }
        })
        console.log($scope.friends);
    }
}]);
```

and

```
.controller('TestFriendCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'APIUser', function($scope, $timeout, APIUser) {

    $scope.friends = [{username: 'coucou'}];

    $scope.change = function(friend) {
        APIUser.find(friend, function(success, data){
            if (success) {
                $scope.friends = angular.copy(data);
            }
        })
        console.log($scope.friends);
    }
}]);
```

In all cases `console.log($scope.friends);` return the expected value

And a view

```
<ion-view class="main-page">
    <ion-content>
        <h1>Friend</h1>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input ng-model="friend" name="friend" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-change="change(friend)">
        </label>
        {{ data.friends[0].username }}
        <ion-list ng-controller="TestFriendCtrl" >
            <ion-item ng-repeat="friend in data.friends" class="item-thumbnail-left">
                <p>{{friend.username}}</p>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

the `$scope.friend` is well updated in the console output but my list does not change.

I tried to add `$scope.$apply` but I have `$digest already in progress`

Comment: should'nt it be  $scope.friends.push (data) ?

Comment: $scope.$apply shall NEVER be used. You have to wrap your code into $timeout(function(){ $scope.friends = data; } );

Comment: try to copy the value of `data` by using : `$scope.friends = angular.copy(data)` . I am pretty sure there is just a bind between $scope.friend and data with the way you are doing it,  then data is deleted when you go out of the callback. That's why you need to copy the value instead of binding it

Comment: I tried both solutions but, doesn't works (I updated the message code)

Comment: Thanks all, I find the error, I removed `ng-controller="TestFriendCtrl"` and now it's works

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, while I don't know what `APIUser` does:

```
.controller('TestFriendCtrl', ['$scope', 'APIUser', function($scope, APIUser) {
    $scope.friends = [{username: 'test'}];

    $scope.change = function(friend) {
        APIUser.find(friend).$promise.then(function(success, data){
            if (success) {
                $scope.friends = data;
                console.log($scope.friends);
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        )};
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your latest update, I assume that may have a link to the . (dot). 
There is plenty of post easily foundable in google explaining why it is not goot to have a direct model without a .dot dilimiter.

Try to change your model with `$scope.myDatas.friends = data`; and change your ng-repeat call to `ng-repeat="friend in myDatas.friends"`

Answer (score 0):

The comment suggesting `angular.copy()` was almost correct, it was just missing the [second parameter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy).  Using `angular.copy()` (or similarly [Lodash's](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) `_.assign()`) you wont lose the reference to the original array instance. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258756/angularjs-losing-reference-to-service-variable-on-re-assignment) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265565/angularjs-promise-is-resolved-before-data-is-loaded/12287364#12287364) for further explanation.

```
.controller('TestFriendCtrl', ['$scope', 'APIUser', function($scope, APIUser) {
    $scope.friends = [{username: 'test'}];

    $scope.change = function(friend) {
        APIUser.find(friend).$promise.then(function(success, data){
            if (success) {
                angular.copy(data, $scope.friends);
                console.log($scope.friends);
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        )};
    }
}]);
```